# "'str' object is not callable" after I tried to break the circular import (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to solve this circular import issue in order to implement unit testing without failure. If I may show you the short version of the previous solution I got:

This....

```
serializer_class = serializers.CompanyMappingSerializer
```

should be changed to This:

```
serializer_class = "serializers.CompanyMappingSerializer"
```

After doing this, the unit tests run fine. However, when I run the api with POSTMAN, it shows this error:

```
TypeError at /api/v1/company/
'str' object is not callable
```

What should I do in this situation?

P.S.:
For more information here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  114.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  505.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  465.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in raise_uncaught_exception
  476.         raise exc

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  502.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nick/work/shiftwork_backend/api/views/company.py" in list
  74.             serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)

File "/Users/nick/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get_serializer
  110.         return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/v1/company/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

and below is the more detailed version of api/company.py

```
...
...
from api.models import Company, Pattern, UserCompany, CompanyMapping, Category, COUNTRY_CODE_CHOICES
from statistics.models import CompanySearch
# from api.serializers import CompanySerializer, PatternSerializer, UserCompanySerializer, CompanyMappingSerializer, CategorySerializer
from api import serializers
from api.views import get_user_company_by_local_id, get_user_pattern_by_local_id
...
...
class CompanyMappingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CompanyMapping.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CompanyMappingSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

Comment: It means that serializer_class is a string,  and I'm guessing you're doing something like ```serializer_class()```  Please include a bit more code and the full error traceback.

Comment: changing a type to a string is really only valid for type annotations, not for actual types-as-first-class-variables -- you'll have to break the actual cycle in all likelihood

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have defined the **`serializer_class`** attribute as *string* rather than a *class*.
Thus it should be as

```
class CompanyMappingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CompanyMapping.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CompanyMappingSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

If you want to omit the *circular import* issue, you can make use of the **`get_serializer_class(...)`** method as,

```
class CompanyMappingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CompanyMapping.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CompanyMappingSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        from api.serializers import CompanyMappingSerializer
        return CompanyMappingSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this a best solution but if you can't do something to break the circular loop you can override your serializer's `get_serializer_class` and add your imports in that method like:

```
 class CompanyMappingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CompanyMapping.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        from api.serializer import CompanyMappingSerializer
        return CompanyMappingSerializer
```

And this should prevent from circular import happening.